# How to integrate Crypto++ into C++ Builder 2010 / [ILINK32 Error]

Tags: compilation, c++builder, crypto++, c++builder-2010

I was trying to compile the following (example) code via C++ Builder 2010:

http://swarmapps.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/a-simplification-wrapper-for-the-crypto-library/

( http://pastebin.com/f6bd13d59 / example.cpp )

( http://pastebin.com/f2fc53f83 / BasicCryptoPPWrap.h )

There were no compiler errors but the linking failed:

> [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(const unsigned char *, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs&)' referenced from E:\TEST\DEBUG\FILE1.OBJ

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

from the same page

> The wrapper is not a standalone
>   solution.  It requires your code to
>   link to libcryptopp and know where the
>   cryptopp header files are found.  The
>   Crypto++  website can help you set up
>   your system.  Once you get the
>   validation suite to run successfully,
>   you will be able to use this wrapper.

Comment: are you using a static or dll version of crypto++?

Comment: I'm using the static version. I can compile cryptest_bds.cbproj without any problems. But I got the ILINK32 errors at the project using the wrapper. Maybe I have to change some project settings? but which?

Comment: have you added the Crypto++ directory to your include directories and the lib directories. (Sorry for asking so trivial questions)

Comment: I don't remember how Builder works (many years ago), but there is some mechanism to add dependencies. Have you added cryptlib as a dependancy?

Comment: Yes I have added the directorys + cryptlib as dependency. I can't get what's wrong with it :/

Comment: Ok, try it the other way. Locate the cryptlib lib file in your disk and add it as an additional library to your project.

Comment: Nice, that's the solution. Thank you very much frag.

Comment: frag could you tell me why mine outputs abnormal program termination after printing key1 and initVec1. When i firstly run this program it catched an exception like invalid key length. I am running win 7 64 bit. I compiled crypto++ well in my machine before. Any advice on how to fix this?